# Python - Split a string into list after a certain number of special characters

Tags: python

I have a python program which does a SOAP request to a server, and it works fine:
I get the answer from the server, parse it, clean it, and when I am done, I end up with a string like that:

`name|value|value_name|default|seq|last_modify|record_type|1|Detail|0|0|20150807115904|zero_out|0|No|0|0|20150807115911|out_ind|1|Partially ZeroOut|0|0|20150807115911|...`

Basically, it is a string with values delimited by "|". I also know the structure of the database I am requesting, so I know that it has 6 columns and various rows. I basically need to split the string after every 6th "|" character, to obtain something like:

```
name|value|value_name|default|seq|last_modify|

record_type|1|Detail|0|0|20150807115904|

zero_out|0|No|0|0|20150807115911|

out_ind|1|Partially ZeroOut|0|0|20150807115911|...
```

Can you tell me how to do that in Python? Thank you!

Comment: Can you not just loop through each character in the string and keep a count of the "|" and split it when the count is divisible by 6?

Comment: @Ryan You _could_ do that, but rather than writing a Python loop that scans the chars one by one  it's quicker to use a function that runs at C speed that can find the delimiters in a more efficient way. An alternative to using the `str.split` method (or perhaps `str.partition`) is to use either `str.index` or `str.find` with an appropriate `start` arg.

Comment: @Ryan: I thought about that, but as PM 2Ring said, I am afraid this would be time-consuming: some of the answers from the server may contain tables with millions of fields, so looping through the text character by character is a no-go. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Thank you all guys for the answers, they all work great! I am just choosing as best the one with more upvotes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a functional-style solution.

```
s = 'name|value|value_name|default|seq|last_modify|record_type|1|Detail|0|0|20150807115904|zero_out|0|No|0|0|20150807115911|out_ind|1|Partially ZeroOut|0|0|20150807115911|'

for row in map('|'.join, zip(*[iter(s.split('|'))] * 6)):
    print(row + '|')
```

**output**

```
name|value|value_name|default|seq|last_modify|
record_type|1|Detail|0|0|20150807115904|
zero_out|0|No|0|0|20150807115911|
out_ind|1|Partially ZeroOut|0|0|20150807115911|
```

For info on how `zip(*[iter(seq)] * rowsize)` works, please see the links at [Splitting a list into even chunks](http://sopython.com/canon/14/splitting-a-list-into-even-chunks).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
a = 'name|value|value_name|default|seq|last_modify|record_type|1|Detail|0|0|20150807115904|zero_out|0|No|0|0|20150807115911|out_ind|1|Partially ZeroOut|0|0|20150807115911|'
b = a.split('|')
c = [b[6*i:6*(i+1)] for i in range(len(b)//6)]  # this is a very workable form of data storage
print('\n'.join('|'.join(i) for i in c))  # produces your desired output

# prints:
#  name|value|value_name|default|seq|last_modify
#  record_type|1|Detail|0|0|20150807115904
#  zero_out|0|No|0|0|20150807115911
#  out_ind|1|Partially ZeroOut|0|0|20150807115911
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = "name|value|value_name|default|seq|last_modify|record_type|1|Detail|0|0|20150807115904|zero_out|0|No|0|0|20150807115911|out_ind|1|Partially ZeroOut|0|0|20150807115911|"
splits = data.split('|')
splits = list(filter(None, splits))  # Filter empty strings
row_len = 6
rows = ['|'.join(splits[i:i + row_len]) + '|' for i in range(0, len(splits), row_len)]
print(rows)
>>> ['name|value|value_name|default|seq|last_modify|', 'record_type|1|Detail|0|0|20150807115904|', 'zero_out|0|No|0|0|20150807115911|', 'out_ind|1|Partially ZeroOut|0|0|20150807115911|']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a flexible generator approach:

```
def splitOnNth(s,d,n, keep = False):
    i = s.find(d)
    j = 1
    while True:
        while i > 0 and j%n != 0:
            i = s.find(d,i+1)
            j += 1
        if i < 0:
            yield s
            return #end generator
        else:
            yield s[:i+1] if keep else s[:i]
            s = s[i+1:]
            i = s.find(d)
            j = 1

#test runs, showing `keep` in action:

test = 'name|value|value_name|default|seq|last_modify|record_type|1|Detail|0|0|20150807115904|zero_out|0|No|0|0|20150807115911|out_ind|1|Partially ZeroOut|0|0|20150807115911|'
for s in splitOnNth(test,'|',6,True): print(s)
print('')
for s in splitOnNth(test,'|',6): print(s)
```

Output:

```
name|value|value_name|default|seq|last_modify|
record_type|1|Detail|0|0|20150807115904|
zero_out|0|No|0|0|20150807115911|
out_ind|1|Partially ZeroOut|0|0|20150807115911|

name|value|value_name|default|seq|last_modify
record_type|1|Detail|0|0|20150807115904
zero_out|0|No|0|0|20150807115911
out_ind|1|Partially ZeroOut|0|0|20150807115911
```

Answer (score 0):

There are really many ways to do it. Even with a loop:

```
a = 'name|value|value_name|default|seq|last_modify|record_type|1|Detail|0|0|20150807115904' \
    '|zero_out|0|No|0|0|20150807115911|out_ind|1|Partially ZeroOut|0|0|20150807115911|'

new_a = []
ind_start, ind_end = 0, 0
for i in range(a.count('|')// 6):
    for i in range(6):
        ind_end = a.index('|', ind_end+1)
    print(a[ind_start:ind_end + 1])
    new_a.append(a[ind_start:ind_end+1])
    ind_start = ind_end+1
```

The print is just to saw the results, you remove it:

```
name|value|value_name|default|seq|last_modify|
record_type|1|Detail|0|0|20150807115904|
zero_out|0|No|0|0|20150807115911|
out_ind|1|Partially ZeroOut|0|0|20150807115911|
```

Comment: Thanks for writing an example that uses `.index`. But you need to handle the possibility of `ValueError: substring not found`. It might be simpler to use `.find` which returns -1 if the substring isn't found.

Comment: You are right. .find is better and has the same output